# Setting up ccache with Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, ccache

I'm trying to set up ccache in Qt Creator on Windows.

Unfortunatelly I couldn't find any good instruction. How to make it working?

I have ccache installed with Cygwin.

edit:

I've tried adding

```
QMAKE_CXX+="ccache g++"
```

as additional parameter in qmake build step.

But in compile output I still have "g++ -c -g -Wall ..." and I suppose it should be "ccache g++ ..."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be:

```
"QMAKE_CXX=ccache g++"
```

And you might need to rerun qmake from the Build menu if QtCreator doesn't update automatically the makefile after you add that parameter.

Comment: I also must set CCACHE_DIR in Windows cause ccache was unable to create $HOME/.ccache

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode the compiler you can use `QMAKE_CXX="ccache $$QMAKE_CXX"` to prefix the existing setting.

Comment: i also must remove precompiled header. In qt it's particularly removing the line: "PRECOMPILED_HEADER=MY_PRECOMP.HPP"

Comment: @alexisdm I am confused, why do you show the quotes including QMAKE, while other answers show quotes only including the```ccache g++``` part?

Answer (score -1):

QtCreator doesn't know about ccache, and besides, it's looking for trouble to mix Cygwin binaries with native binaries on Windows.